Hom doesn't always commute with localization counterexample
I'm working through Vakil's Rising Sea book, which briefly notes (Example 1.6.10) that the $\text{Hom}$ functor does not always commute with the localization functor. A quick counterexample is provided after an exercise on proving that the two functors commute whenever you have a finitely presented module.
Vakil provides this counterexample to show that $\text{Hom}$ does not always commute with localization:
\begin{align*}
S^{-1} \text{Hom}_\mathcal{A}(M, N) \ncong \text{Hom}_{S^{-1} \mathcal{A}}(S^{-1}M, S^{-1}N)
\end{align*}
where $\mathcal{A} = N = \mathbb{Z}$, $M = \mathbb{Q}$, and $S = \mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$.
I have a feeling that this counterexample is obvious, but I am failing to see why it is true or even where to begin. I would appreciate if any hints could be provided.
Thanks!

can you work out $\hom_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z})$ and do you know what $S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$ would be here?

On the LHS we have the localization of $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z})$. This hom is zero! A maximally elementary argument is the following: suppose $f : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is a homomorphism, and consider any of its values $f(q) = k, q \in \mathbb{Q}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now, what could $f \left( \frac{q}{2k} \right)$ possibly be? Since $f$ is a homomorphism it must staisfy $2k f \left( \frac{q}{2k} \right) = f(q) = k$. But it must also be an integer. This is only possible if $k = 0$, and since $q$ was arbitrary, it follows that $f(q) = 0$ for all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$.
The general form of this argument is that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a divisible abelian group, meaning for every $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists an element $\frac{q}{n}$ such that $n \frac{q}{n} = q$, and the image of a divisible abelian group remains divisible. But no nonzero element of $\mathbb{Z}$ is divisible.
Meanwhile, on the RHS we have $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q})$, which is nonzero.

Here's a conceptual explanation of why this isomorphism doesn't hold in general. By the universal property of localization the RHS can be identified as the homset
$$\text{Hom}_{S^{-1} A}(S^{-1} M, S^{-1} N) \cong \text{Hom}_A(M, S^{-1} N)$$
so we are looking at $A$-module maps $M \to S^{-1} N$. On the LHS we are looking at the localization of $A$-module maps $M \to N$. It's clear that if we divide an $A$-module map $f : M \to N$ by some elements of $S$, we get an $A$-module map $M \to S^{-1} N$, so there is a natural map from the LHS to the RHS. But it isn't necessarily surjective in general (and it isn't in the above example): to go the other way, from an $A$-module map $M \to S^{-1} N$ to the localization of an $A$-module map $M \to N$, we have to be able to clear denominators, and if $M$ is not finitely generated we might be able to write down a homomorphism $M \to S^{-1} N$ which involves dividing by infinitely many elements of $S$ which can't be put under a common denominator.
This happens in our example with $M = \mathbb{Q}$ - it is not possible to clear the denominators of any nonzero homomorphism $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ - but another example (my favorite example!) which I think makes this issue with finite generation and clearing denominators maximally transparent is to instead take $M = \mathbb{Z}[x] \cong \bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$, the free abelian group on countably many generators, and $N = \mathbb{Z}$. Then the LHS is
$$\mathbb{Q} \otimes \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[x], \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Q} \otimes \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}};$$
explicitly this means we take homomorphisms $f : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}$ (of abelian groups, not rings!), which are just given by $\mathbb{N}$-tuples of integers, then localize this. But the RHS is
$$\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}[x], \mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}};$$
here we are taking homomorphisms $f : \mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{Q}$, or equivalently $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Q}$, which are $\mathbb{N}$-tuples of rationals. Now we can see the denominator issue really clearly; the RHS contains elements like $\left( 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \dots \right)$ which involve dividing by infinitely many natural numbers that can't be put under a common denominator, while on the LHS we have to be able to use a common denominator. This counterexample also shows that localization doesn't commute with infinite products.
Strictly speaking, this is a counterexample showing that the natural map is not an isomorphism; "the natural map is an isomorphism" is what we mean by "commutes," formally. But it does happen to be true that the two homs above are abstractly isomorphic (assuming the axiom of choice), since they are both $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces of the same dimension. So the counterexample with $M = \mathbb{Q}$ proves the stronger statement that there is no isomorphism in general, even an unnatural one.

 For a more general and abstract discussion where I also use a version of this counterexample see here.


Wow thanks for the detailed explanation! I had a feeling the answer would be simple. In my attempts, I had just assumed Hom(Q, N) would be non-trivial. I faced the issue you point out where it is easy to go from the LHS to the RHS but not vice-versa because you can‘t clear denominators. I couldn’t figure out a formal way to show this prevents the isomorphism generally. Thanks for the help!

@Ethan: the formal way you show that something doesn't hold is you find a counterexample, that's all. Sooner or later you learn to keep a nice big stock of counterexamples available; this is one of mine. And you're welcome!
